# IIS 8.5 Win 8.1 pro localHost not working

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have researched for days and not found an answer.  I have used both google and Stack and MDSN so I finally thought it is time to ask the question.  I am a new developer I completed my first assignment and my computer died.  I got Win 8.1 pro and IIS 8.5 and now I am tasked with making that work with SQL 2012.  I have it so I can load up the localhost to the first page of the app which is a login and then when I am debuging using Visual Studio after I start to log in 
the first call to the db this comes up

An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
Then I get the same message again and then it sends me to the error page.

I am an IIS newbie, but I have ensured IUSER has the correct authorization and I have checked all of the web.configs, as well as the applicationHost file.  This has to be a IIS problem is what I have come up but I would gladly be wrong if someone told me I was wrong and corrected.  Thanks for the help.

Code Example

The first call to db where the first error pops up

MYapp.GlobalDataService.GlobalDataServiceClient gdc = new Myapp.Proxy.GlobalDataService.GlobalDataServiceClient();

ReadLogosResult result = gdc.GetLogos(_customerId, region_id, branch_id);

```
    if (result != null)
    {
        logoContent = result.Logo;
    }
```

This is after clicking login
        public static int GetUserId(IIdentity contextIdentity)
        {
            FormsIdentity identity = contextIdentity as FormsIdentity;

```
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("cannot cast context identity to FormsIdentity type");
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(identity.Ticket.UserData.Split(';')[0]);
    }
```

Then this
            for (int i = 0; i < ContextKeys.Length; i++)
            {
                string ContextKey = ContextKeys[i];
                if (ContextKey == "appErr")
                {
                    obj = (Exception)HttpContext.Current.Application["appErr"];
                    HttpContext.Current.Application.Remove("appErr");
                }
                if (ContextKey == "userId")
                {
                    user = (int)HttpContext.Current.Application["userId"];
                    HttpContext.Current.Application.Remove("userId");
                }
            }
errors out Object reference not set to an instance of an object
then goes to our customer error page

Comment: Can you please post you service and client code?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what client code are you referring to.

Comment: How are you trying to consume your service? Is there any client application you are using or any tool?

Comment: it is a web app that allows the connection to database to pull user information right off the bat once they log in.  I have tried pinging my db made sure TCP/IP connection is enabled everything tells me SQL Server is connected properly but the connection wont establish with my localhost

Comment: Mate, please post your code if you can.

Comment: web.config
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FamusEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/myModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Matrix-Dev;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I got it figured out Thanks for looking though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out. I needed to install HTTPActivation in WCF.